# I am having trouble configuring key code layout with css and html elements for 2 column layout and ned some help. Color Key Code

Tags: html, css, layout

I have some html with css and I am trying to perform a layout of 2 columns  70/30 split (I have done this part ). I have two table elements one over the other in the right hand column and one of these needs to be a color key with a descriptor text.

I attach a picture of what I need and the current code that I have.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two columns next to each other */
.columna {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; 
}
/* Create two columns next to each other */
.columnb {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; 
}

/* Create two columns next to each other */
.columnc {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px; 
}
/* Create two columns next to each other */
.columnd {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px; 
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

div.sideborder {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
div.colorKey1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
div.colorKey2 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}
div.colorKey3 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

span.awp {
  display: inline; 
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two  Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="columna" style="background-color:#aea;">
<p> stuff here </p>
<div>Stuff Goes Here</div>

  </div>
  <div class="columnb" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xxl-4 sideborder" style="text-align: center;"><b >Color Key</b>
<div class="card" style="border:4 solid black;" >
<table class="customer-card" ><tbody>
<tr><td colspan="12" class="" style="text-align: center;"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="columnd colorKey2" style="background-color:#91a"></td><td class="columnc ">Stuff Goes Here</td></tr>
<tr><td class="columnd colorKey3" style="background-color:#68d;"></td><td><span class="awp">Stuff Goes Here</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class="columnd colorKey2" style="background-color:#511;"></td><td>Stuff Goes Here</td></tr>

</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
<div> <p></p>     </div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xxl-4 sideborder" ><b>Properties</b>
<div class="card"  >
<table class="customer-card" ><tbody>
<tr><td rowspan="4" class="img"><img src="/demo/Content/avatar/avatar3.jpg"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="name"><a href="javascript:;"><b>Info</b></a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="contact">Scada Man, Summer</td></tr><tr><td class="country">Somewhere, USA</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Html Layout that Iam trying to achieve]

Comment: You may find that, at least to start with, abandoning float and Bootstrap and just looking at implementing things with CSS grid will make life more straightforward.

Comment: You have `<table>` elements? Why, none of what you show here is tabular data.

Comment: @AHaworth I am open to it - how to do it ?

Comment: @DavidThomas in this particular case no data will populate it like that, in another use case I will have tabular data for Cards .. I just need to be able to get the layout for the code key mainly . any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid